# Public Share link in Alfresco Community edition 4

Tags: alfresco

I saw that the Alfresco Cloud edition has nice share/publish features:

[image: public link]
<sub>(source: [alfresco.com](http://www.alfresco.com/sites/www/files/features-share.png))</sub>

Now I could not find this in the community edition, even though I found a place in the `Admin Console` under `Content Publishing` called `Channel Manager` where you can add different publish channels. I did not find a way to make use of them though!

Still my main question would be how to be able to generate public links for non users to access certain files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alfresco Cloud is very new (it only went [GA last week](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/alfresco-in-the-cloud/)!). As such, it features quite a few new bits since the latest Alfresco Community 4.0 release, which came out at the start of the year. The ["Public Share" feature](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/2012_Product_Roadmap#Public_File_Sharing_Links_Available) is one of those.

The Alfresco [2012 Product Roadmap](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/2012_Product_Roadmap) has been announced, which should give you an idea of what features are likely to be coming in the next Community Release, later this year. Almost all of the new features from the Cloud have either already been merged to Head already, or will be merged before the next Community release. I don't know if the public sharing will be merged or not (you'd need to pin down one of the product managers for a definitive answer on if that's something that'll be merged to community/enterprise, or if it's something that's too specific to the Cloud setup (so can't easily be re-used by other setups). In the mean time, you can keep an eye on the checkins to HEAD!

(If the feature you're interested in from Cloud has already been committed to head, then you can grab a [nightly build](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Nightly_Community_Build) and start playing with it aleady!)

Comment: The Public Share feature (aka "QuickShare"), like just about everything else you see in Alfresco Cloud, will eventually make it into Community Edition and Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Wohoo! Great news :) Thank you guys!