# Adding public link to a document in Alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco

I have installed alfresco-community-4.0, and want to add public link to a document so that it can be accessed publicly without passing on credentials. Please tell me the process to do it. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Public Share link in Alfresco Community edition 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178028/public-share-link-in-alfresco-community-edition-4)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Guest Home in the repository.
This space is dedicated for storing contents that you want to make public.

Comment: But you still have to log in to follow an external URL link to a file in Guest Home..?